# Finding the vertical and horizontal asymptotes of the function $f(x) = \frac{e^x(x + 1)}{e^{2x}(x^2 - 1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-functions

I am to find the vertical and horizontal asymptotes of this given function:

$$f(x) = \frac{e^x(x + 1)}{e^{2x}(x^2 - 1)}$$

To find the vertical asymptote,I think I equate the bottom line to zero and whatever my $x$ gives is the vertical asymptote?
But I don't know how to solve $e^{2x}(x^2-1) = 0$. Is it going to be $x = +1,-1$?  Hence, the vertical asymptotes are $1$ and $-1$.

To find horizontal asymptotes, I think I should find the limit as $x \to \infty$ and $x \to -\infty$.
I don't know how to go about this.

Can someone please help?

Comment: You should first simplify to get $f(x) = \frac{1}{e^x(x-1)}$ then you see that the vertical asymptote is only at $x=1$. The horizontal asymptote is answered below.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just calculate the value of $y$ at $x\to-\infty \;\text{and} \; x
\to\infty$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{e^x(x+1)}{e^{2x}(x^2-1)}=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x(x+1)}{e^{2x}(x^2-1)}=0$$

As limit exists for $x\to\infty$,
$$y=0$$
is the horizontal asymptote.

For vertical asymptote, you must find values of $x$ for which $y\to\infty$.

$$y=f(x)=\frac{e^x(x+1)}{e^{2x}(x^2-1)}$$

As denominator goes to $0$ for $x=\pm1$, we will check limit of $y$ at these values.

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{e^x(x+1)}{e^{2x}(x^2-1)}=-\frac{e}{2}$$
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{e^x(x+1)}{e^{2x}(x^2-1)}=\infty$$

Since $y
\to\infty$ for $x=1$, $$x=1$$ is the vertical asymptote.

$x=-1$, is not the vertical asymptote as limit of $y$ is defined at this value.

Comment: So the vertical asymptotes are +1 and -1 right?

Comment: @yowhatsup123, no only $x=1$ is the vertical asymptote.