# How to find the vertical and horizontal asymptotes of rational functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$f(x) = \frac{e^x(x + 1)}{(x^2 - 1)e^{2x}}$$

How would I go about solving this problem? I've tried all ways I think is possible.

Comment: Click the blue hyperlink for the question. Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: Function simplifies.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting a link to an image since links can get broken and images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please edit your question to show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: please see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420140/finding-the-vertical-and-horizontal-asymptotes-of-this-given-function

Comment: I have taken the liberty to suppress "difficult" in your title because it is very subjective (because it it depends upon the person (I would call it personaly "easy" ...). Moreover, its presence does not attract more people...

Comment: @HanHan you mentioned you tried all way you thought of. It is advisable to post one or two of your tries, because as of yet, I am believing the amount of times you tried this exercise is zero as this problem I'd call it "trivial", advanced-middle-school-level or average-high-school-level.